# Using Python 3.8, I would like to extract text from a random PDF file

Tags: typeerror, python-3.8

I would like to import a PDF file and find the most common words.

```
import PyPDF2

# Open the PDF file and read the text
pdf_file = open("nita20.pdf", "rb")
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)
text = ""
for page in range(pdf_reader.pages):
    text += pdf_reader.getPage(page).extractText()
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: '_VirtualList' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

How to resolve this issue? So I can extract every word from the PDF file, thanks.

Comment: `pdf_reader.pages` is not in the docs, use:  [len(reader.pages)](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/modules/PdfReader.html#:~:text=version%201.28.0%3A%20Use-,len(reader.pages),-instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some deprecation warnings on your code, but this works (tested on Python 3.11, PyPDF2 version: 3.0.1)

```
import PyPDF2

# Open the PDF file and read the text
pdf_file = open("..\test.pdf", "rb")
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)
text = ""
i=0
print(len(pdf_reader.pages))
for page in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
    text += pdf_reader.pages[i].extract_text()
    i=i+1

print(text)
```

Comment: Thank you, there is a typo 'text'